# List all XML nodes with their namespace prefixes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I would like to list all XML nodes with the namespace prefix in SQL Server 2019.

The result from query below does not contain the namespace prefix for the nodes. Is it possible to list `<cbc:ID>` as "cbc:ID" instead of only "ID"?

```
DECLARE @xml xml;
SET @xml = '<Order xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<cbc:CustomizationID>urn:fdc:peppol.eu:poacc:trns:order:3</cbc:CustomizationID>
<cbc:ProfileID>urn:fdc:peppol.eu:poacc:bis:ordering:3</cbc:ProfileID>
<cbc:ID>1513999</cbc:ID>
</Order>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    DEFAULT 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2'
    ,'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2' AS cac
    ,'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2' AS cbc
)
SELECT C.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS node_name
FROM @xml.nodes('/Order/*') AS T(C);
```

Comment: XPath has `name()` function as well as the a `local-name()` function, I haven't checked whether SQL server supports it, try on your own.

Comment: Aside... `;` is a statement terminator character, not a statement "begininator." Note also that, _Although the semicolon isn't required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version._ Ref: [Transact-SQL syntax conventions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql)

Comment: The namespace prefixes have no meaning in XML, they are just a way to link elements to their defined namespace URI - not unlike how aliases are used in SQL Server queries to link columns to the referenced table or view. The namespace prefixes you use in your XQuery don't have to be the same as the ones in the XML data, so long as both versions reference the same namespace URI, i.e.: it might be `ccts` in the XML data but `foo` in your XQuery. So given all that... shouldn't you be more interested in the element's namespace URI?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.